# "Dead Kernel" Anaconda-Jupyter Cling C++ Windows

Tags: windows, anaconda, jupyter, conda, cling

I newly installed Anaconda (v.4.3.1) and used a conda command to install cling for a C++ kernel on Jupyter. I used `conda install -c conda-forge cling=0.3.post`

I am on Windows 8.1. I can't seem to find an answer on how to resolve this: I'm getting a 'Dead Kernel' error upon opening a notebook with any C++11, C++14 or C++17 kernel. I have not at all been able to use the c++ kernels after installation. Python3 kernel works completely fine. Below is a screenshot of the error I get.

[Dead Kernel: Error Message Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4nDx.png)

Answer (score 1):

For future errors: look at the console window that opens up when you start the notebook server.  That will report Python exceptions.

For this case, I think you found what I recently discovered: cling's Jupyter kernel does not currently work on Windows.  It uses the fcntl module to make pipes it uses for input/output non-blocking.  fcntl only works with *nix operating systems.  You'll have to wait until they change it up.

Comment: The issue was commented on in December 2018 with [the same comment](https://github.com/conda-forge/cling-feedstock/issues/9). Not really a shock, even Cling itself doesn't work (adding `int x = 3;` works, but attempting to print it with `x` crashes the entire program). Most of that is on Cling though, the official binaries don't include Windows either. For now, I suppose using WSL or hosting Jupyter on a UNIX server is the way to go.